# Monotonic counter / Last-Modified / ETag for updated resource?

Tags: http, server, client

I am working in a list application. When the client updates the state of an item, only that updated item is return (as opposed to return the whole list, which might be huge), which poses a problem of concurrent access to the list (different clients have different items out-of-date).
Right now I am not considering the case in which two clients update the same item, but different items. To solve this problem, I have thought in using:

1. a custom header that monotonically increases with any request that modifies a list. If the client sees that between two requests originated by it there is a difference of 1, the client knows it has the most up-to-date version of the list and its items.
2. using the standard Last-Modified header, based on the date with 1" granularity
3. using an etag, holding the monotonic counter depicted in (1)

What would be the advice, here?

Comment: There's not enough detail here to give a definitive answer, but this sounds like a classic use case for `ETag`. See [RFC 7232](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232#section-3.1). Do you see any advantage to 1 and 2 over 3?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry No, I do not see any clear advantage. I think is mostly related to standards and conventions, and I am pretty new to web app programming. Thank you for your answer, though :-)